# android annotations Error:(52, 42) error: cannot find symbol class Activity_

Tags: java, android

i'm making a project with AA(Android Annotations), but, sometimes run and another times show this error.

Help!

Error code:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:assembleDebug]
/Users/MacDeveloper/Desktop/projectTest/app/src/main/java/co/com/barricade/model/push/FCMService.java
Error:(30, 25) error: cannot find symbol class MasterActivity_
/Users/MacDeveloper/Desktop/projectTest/app/src/main/java/co/com/barricade/ui/content/categorias/CategoriasBigListFragment.java
Error:(52, 42) error: cannot find symbol class SucursalActivity_
/Users/MacDeveloper/Desktop/projectTest/app/src/main/java/co/com/barricade/ui/MasterActivity.java
Error:(82, 40) error: cannot find symbol class OfertaActivity_
Error:(86, 42) error: cannot find symbol class SucursalActivity_
Error:(89, 38) error: cannot find symbol class PerfilActivity_
Error:(90, 38) error: cannot find symbol class PreferenciasCategoriasActivity_
Error:(91, 38) error: cannot find symbol class TerminiosYCondicionesActivity_
Error:(92, 48) error: cannot find symbol class HistorialCuponesActivity_
Error:(94, 53) error: cannot find symbol class NotificacionesActivity_
Error:(97, 31) error: cannot find symbol class LoginActivity_
/Users/MacDeveloper/Desktop/projectTest/app/src/main/java/co/com/barricade/ui/content/categorias/CategoriasSmallListFragment.java
Error:(53, 42) error: cannot find symbol class SucursalActivity_
/Users/MacDeveloper/Desktop/projectTest/app/src/main/java/co/com/barricade/ui/content/categorias/CategoriasMapFragment.java
Error:(54, 42) error: cannot find symbol class SucursalActivity_
/Users/MacDeveloper/Desktop/projectTest/app/src/main/java/co/com/barricade/ui/content/cercadeti/almacenes/CercaDeTiAlmacenesBigListFragment.java

Error:(70, 5) error: org.androidannotations.annotations.Background can only be used in a class annotated with @org.androidannotations.annotations.EApplication, @interface org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity, @interface org.androidannotations.annotations.EViewGroup, @interface org.androidannotations.annotations.EView, @interface org.androidannotations.annotations.EBean, @interface org.androidannotations.annotations.EService, @interface org.androidannotations.annotations.EIntentService, @interface org.androidannotations.annotations.EReceiver, @interface org.androidannotations.annotations.EProvider, @interface org.androidannotations.annotations.EFragment.
```

Warning:(71, 20) Element getVars() invalidated by BackgroundHandler
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 46.817 secs
>   Information:92 errors
>   Information:1 warning
>   Information:See complete output in console

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Hi @DoronYakovlev-Golani in any import where call a Activity, example "MainActivity_.java"

Comment: Do you put underscores at the end of your classes?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using public access specifier before method name.
Change

```
private void getVars() 
to 
public void getVars()
```